# Performance issue with django postgres delete

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, sql-delete

In my application I have a caching mechanism for requests to a different API. This is designed to store the request and response for 24 hours.

Every-time the 24 hour limit is over the entry gets deleted from the database before creating a new request and saving the result again in the cache.

It seems like there is an issue with a delete, only from time to time. Some of my delete requests take multiple minutes, even though the caching database has only around 100 entries and consists of a url, params (md5), body (md5), response and created date field. I analyse the performance through sentry. Below you can find a screenshot of the event. As you can see there is also a select beforehand that has no performance issue.

[image: sentry event]

Furthermore it happens that the delete has no performance issue.
The database is a postgres database that runs on a different dedicated server.

I already tried to recreate the database but without any success.
I would assume that the ssh connection should not be the problem, because the select before the delete runs without any issue (and there are other selects beforehand as well. I also checked and debugged the code but there is nothing that I see either.

Any idea what can cause this low-performing behaviour and how I can overcome this?

Comment: For your solution I would use cron jobs to clear cache every 24 hour. But what I would do is to use redis or something like that (DynamoDB) and use ttl as 24h for it so it will be removed without any additional affort.

Comment: Yes that is a workaround that would solve the issue. It is also not really necessary to delete the records, or at least not on a daily basis. But nevertheless I'm curious what the issue here is also to avoid this happening in the future